# Building a JSON encoded object

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

I'm submitting data to an API. It wants the format like this:

```
{
  "subscribers": [{
    "email": "john@acme.com",
    "time_zone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "custom_fields": {
      "name": "John Doe"
    }
  }]
}
```

I'm building the JSON object in PHP like this:

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [
        ['email' => $email],
        ['custom_fields'] => [
            ['name' => "Bob"]
        ]
    ]   
];
$encoded = json_encode($subscriberInfo);
```

The API is rejecting `['custom_fields']`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the API require the exact format as you posted? If so you are missing the `time_zone` part of your array. And you might want to ask the dev of the API for more information.

Comment: time zone is optional

Comment: Their support sucks. I've been waiting for 2 days for other answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct array format. You are using wrong array format.

[**Try this snippet here**](https://eval.in/803944)

```
$subscriberInfo = array(
    'subscribers' => array(
        array(
          'email' => "s",
          'custom_fields'=>
             array('name' => "Bob")
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

API should be rejecting 'email' field also.

It should be;

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [
        [
            'email' => $email,
            'custom_fields' => [
                'name' => "Bob"
            ]
        ]
    ]   
];

$encoded = json_encode($subscriberInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your offset is simply incorrect. You should not have the "[" on line 4 of your object, after 'custom_field':

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [
        ['email' => $email],
        ['custom_fields' =>
            ['name' => "Bob"]
        ]
    ]   
];
$encoded = json_encode($subscriberInfo);
```

... returns:

```
"subscribers":[{"email":""},{"custom_fields":{"name":"Bob"}}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/803954)**

```
$subscriberInfo = [
    'subscribers' => [[
        'email' => $email,
        'custom_fields' => 
            ['name' => "Bob"]
        ]
    ]   
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
<?php
$subscriberEx = array(
    'subscribers' => array(
        array('email' => "s",
        'custom_fields'=>
            array('name' => "Bob")
        )
    )
);
$subscriber_encoded = json_encode($subscriberEx);
echo $subscriber_encoded;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
{  
   "subscribers":[  
      {  
         "email":"s",
         "custom_fields":{  
            "name":"Bob"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```